# Kubernetes Ingress rules are not followed, Default backend is reached instead

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using Nginx-ingress-controller
this is the yaml file for ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  labels:
    app: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: hello-kubernetes-first
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: testk8s.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /test
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-service
                port:
                  number: 8001
```

when I do reach `testk8s.com/test` I'm getting `Cannot GET /test`
and when do reach `testk8s.com` default backend works.

Comment: it could be due to backend service not have any path with /test you might need to rewrite path from ingress if required.

Comment: no i test this service with default backend it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this once

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  defaultBackend:
  service:
    name: hello-kubernetes-first
    port:
      number: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: it gave me 503 error, because we did not specify the host in yaml file

Comment: 503 mean your service is not running or wrong service name.

Comment: But you didn't specify a host in yaml file

Comment: yes that you can add it as per need shared that file for ref, check ingress class