# Disable Nginx ingress controller default backend

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using the Nginx ingress controller in a GKE cluster.

My nginx rule has a

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          ...
```

The proble is that if my application returns a 401 in one of the routes nginx is using the default backend and returning a 500 HTML page.

The app is supposed to be returning the code 401 and a json because the path being `/`

I want my app to be returning the response for all the codes and don't use the default backend.

I have tried to change `Prefix` to `ImplementationSpecific`. And adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209906/kubernetes-ingress-rules-are-not-followed-default-backend-is-reached-instead) but nothing changes

Comment: ingress is responsible for routing the traffic, if a request is routed to the app (and the app gets 401) -- ingress works fine, and default backend is not used... why do you blame on ingress?

Comment: @star67the default backend is used because it returns a 500. The 401 is the one the app should return. For all other routes it like 200 it returns the app's response.